# How does precision and recall work in this situation?

Tags: nlp, precision-recall

Consider the following text, which has been manually annotated using IO-style annotation for persons (PER), locations (LOC) and organizations (ORG).

> Chicago/LOC Mayor/O Rahm/PER Emanuel/PER, a/O former/O White/ORG
>   House/ORG aide/O to/O US/LOC Presidents/O Barack/PER Obama/PER and/O
>   Bill/PER Clinton/PER, on/O Friday/O joined/O the/O Ready/O For/O
>   Hillary/PER group/O that/O is/O urging/O former/O US/LOC Secretary/O
>   of/O State/O Hillary/PER Clinton/PER to/O run/O for/O president/O in/O
>   2016/O.

Consider the following feature assignments f(FEATURES,LABEL), which indicate assigning LABEL upon observing FEATURE, where w is the current token, and w-1 is the previous token.

```
f1(isCapitalized(w), PER)

f2(label(w-1) = PER, PER)

f3(isCapitalized(w), LOC)

f4(lemma(w-1) = "president" OR "mayor", PER)
```

Based on the observed data, compute precision and recall for each of the features above, assuming that each of them is used in isolation in order to assign labels, and each starts with an unlabelled text.

How should I calculate the precision/ recall, in this situation?
Should I consider, for example, Rahm Emanuel as one True Positive feature? Or each token is a true positive feature? Or each token is a false positive as Rahm Emanuel is actually a single true positive feature?

Comment: This https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51301 may help!

Comment: I know the formulas...: P = tp/(tp+fp)
R = tp/(tp+fn)

Comment: Run your classifier for each of the above features (individually) and calculate precision and recall using the formulas. True Positive will be, for example, if first letter is R and if classified as PER, and it was actually a PER. False positive will be for e.g., first character was R, it classified it as PER but it wasn't a PER. False negative will be for e.g., first character was R, it didn't classified it as PER, but it was a PER. This way you will have 4 confusion matrices, one for each feature.

Comment: Should I consider the /O(outside) tags as well while calculating the precision and recall?

Comment: Yes you have to because those are tags which are used by your classifier!

Comment: I think I solved it. The gold standard /Os are the TN.

Comment: that's great! :-)